# get absolute div outside relative parent

Tags: html, css

I have a `position:relative` element named `#container`. The reason why it is relative is because I need it to have a `z-index` so that it overlaps some shadow I have on my page.

I also have a tooltip called `#outside` that I'd like to position outside of `#container` but the javascript tooltip positions adds the DOM inside of the `#container`.

Does anyone know how I can still achieve a `overflow-y:scroll` but get the `#outside` literally outside of my element?

It doesn't matter how I do it, as long as my `#container` can have a z-index so it overlaps my shadow.

Here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n26gt881/) (shadow is not in this fiddle)

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />hi
    <br />
    <div id="outside">outside</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container {
    z-index:9;
    position:relative;
    border:1px solid red;
    width:50px;
    height:100px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    overflow-x:visible;
}
#outside {
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;
    left:75px;
}
```

Comment: I don't believe it's possible to do what you're thinking without some hacky solution - an absolutely positioned element within an element with `position:relative` is going to be positioned according to the parent div. And getting it to appear outside when you have overflow hidden is not possible. However, why not apply `z-index` to an element with `position:absolute` (I'm referring to the parent element here)?

Comment: @TimMcClure I don't have an `overflow:hidden`? I can apply or take away whatever. I just need `#container` to be able to gracefully go over a div's shadow (hence `z-index:9`)

Comment: Oh sorry, misread that when you said `overflow-y:scroll`. Can you put the shadow in the jsfiddle so I can see what you're referencing? What's the issue with applying `z-index` to an element with `position:absolute`?

Comment: You can always switch to position fixed for the outside element.

Comment: @TimMcClure here you go http://jsfiddle.net/n26gt881/1/ I'm not sure what you mean, even `position:absolute` on `#container` still doesn't do the trick.

Comment: @evilrobotz position fixed does not work

Comment: Ah ok, I've had this issue before. The `position` property is not the issue here - it's your `overflow` properties. Even when you set `overflow-y` to hidden,scroll, etc while setting `overflow-x` to `visible`, elements will still be hidden. Setting the `#container` element to `position:absolute` has no effect.

Comment: Yea, that seems to be my issue :( Any idea on how to fix it/workaround? @TimMcClure

Comment: Take a look at my jsfiddle in my answer and see if that works for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discussed in the comments is the real issue - setting `overflow-y:scroll` also hides elements on the x-axis. The workaround is to wrap the elements you want to scroll in their own overflow wrapping div. See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n26gt881/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Could you use fixed positioning instead?

```
...
#outside {
    position:fixed;
    top:10px;
    left:75px;
}
```

If needed, some js animation when scrolling could keep it where you want it.

Comment: OP stated in post comments that `position:fixed` will not work in his case.